# Estou com problema para retirar uma numeração do html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com problema para retirar uma numeração do html já tentei de tudo e nada o slide fica assim:

E como eu mudaria de img pra text?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Secure Elo Bosting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mains.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
      <section id="slide">
        <div class="ban">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">

            <li>
                <img src="img/1.jpg" >

            </li>

            <li>
                <img src="img/2.jpg" >
            </li>

            <li>
                <img src="img/3.jpg" >

            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

codigo ss:

```
.flexslider{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    position: relative;
}

.flexslider ul li {
list-style: none;
}

.slides,
.slides li,
.slides li img{
    width: 100%;
}

.slides li{
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}



/* RESPONSIVE ========== */


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){

    .flexslider{
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: none;
    }

    .slides li{
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slides li img{
        width: 600px;
    }


}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
    .slides li img{
        transform: translateX(-90px);
    }


}
```

Comment: mas o que você quer fazer? remover o número ? ou coloca-lo em outro lugar?

Comment: eu queria tirar aqueles 1 2 3

Comment: Velho, tenta colocar o seu código num snippet, tipo, upa as imagens num site e troca a url, pega os scripts de js e coloca tudo dentro para que possamos simular a situação e ver o que acontece?

Comment: São 3 codigos de js como eu faria pra por todos eles num snippet? tem como?

Comment: Tipo procura por "nome_do_codigo CDN" CDN é um link direto para você por no seu codigo

Comment: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/flexslider tipo esse ó <<<<<<<<< abre ai e da uma olhada

Comment: pow não estou entendendo kkk tipo tem um script q é bem pequeno da pra passar aqui tem esse ; jquery-3.1.0.min e tem jquery.flexslider q pelo oq vi no site é esse : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.4/jquery.flexslider.js

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
  prevText: "",
  nextText: "",
  pauseOnAction: false,
  slideshowSpeed: 3000,
  touch: true
 });

});

Comment: Isso é alguma configuração do Plugin que vc usou para fazer a Galeria. Vc tem que ir na documentação do Plugin e procurar por algo assim: Pagination="True" ai vc coloca "False" no Script, Normalmente esses plugins de Slider tem essa opção. Qual vc usou?

Comment: jquery.flexslider e  jquery-3.1.0.min provavelmente isso está no jquery.flexslider não é?

Comment: @Felipe calma, vou te mostrar como funciona, dessa vez eu edito sua pergunta para te ensinar , ai nas proximas você consegue fazer sozinho ok? já edito e te mostro

Comment: blz @LeonardoBonetti vlw brother.

Comment: @Felipe me diz quais scripts que vocÊ fez ... tipo o main.js é seu :? me fala todos que é de sua autoria pq ai eu n vou conseguir inserir esses

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $('.flexslider').flexslider({ prevText: "", nextText: "", pauseOnAction: false, slideshowSpeed: 3000, touch: true }); });  aq mano.

Answer (score 1):

Então cara, sou novo por aqui e sei bem pouco de html CSS e tal, mas creio que posso lhe ajudar. Listas adicionam automaticamente essa numeração ai, porém com css você consegue estilizar a lista. Para deixar a lista sem numeros basta na parte do css do seu codigo (.slides li) você adicionar o atributo "list-style-type = none;". No link abaixo na documentação do css você pode achar outras formas de estilizar a lista https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Comment: vlw bro, eu já tinha tentando isso tb, o problema é na script mesmo .